Making all objects function as a single object
I have a lot of sub-objects like clothes and hair and fingernails that I just want to remain where they are as if they were part of a single thing.  They don't need them to do anything special.  But I want them to remain discreet so I can give them different colors and materials.
I have the armature working finally but the sub-objects don't move with t.
The options as I understand them are:
a) Join them into a single mesh.  That will work, but then the material and color options are gone.  (Is there a better way to accomplish that?)
b) Group them.  So far as I can tell this does nothing except keep the workspace clean.
c) Create a collection.  When I do this I lose the weighted rigging option.
d) Parent them to something?  The question is to what.  The body object, or directly to the bones?  Will the boot them bend along with the ankle?  Is that even possible?
Thanks to everyone for their patience with my silly questions.  I very much appreciate it.

Hard to answer this question without knowing how much expertise you got in the certain fields... do you know how rigging a character works? The character has to be parented to the armature and vertex groups with weights define how the bones move the mesh. So, if you know that, you should know that "sub-objects" will not move if they have no relation to the armature and no weights - joining them into a single mesh will not change that, they still need the mesh in vertex groups with weights to be moved by the armature.

The other thing is: do you know how materials and texturing work? Because I'm not sure what material and color options you are talking about which are gone when you join the "sub-objects" into a single mesh. A mesh can have many different materials in different areas, actually you could give every single face its individual material. Okay, I'm exaggerating - I do not know if Blender limits the number of materials per object to something, while a mesh can have tens of thousands of faces and more...

What do you mean with c? As long as your objects are parented, even if they are in separate collections, they influence their children as expected.

You can do a, no problem.
The material tab contains a "list" of materials, and you can add as many as you want. In edit mode it's possible to select faces, select a material and click "assign". This allows a single mesh to have different materials.
You can also do d, if you parent an object to a bone, it will follow the bone.
You can probably also parent as many things as you want to the armature and weight paint.

Appreciated.  Thank you.
